# Null pointer exception not being thrown during assignment operation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, reference, assignment-operator

In java assignment operation , for an assignment operation : the right hand side expression is evaluated first and then assigned to the left hand side.
In the code snippet below , I was expecting assignment operation to throw a Null Pointer Exception but it does not. Can someone explain why?

```
public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class1 c = new Class1();
    c.x = tell(c = null);
  }

  private static int tell(Object o) {
    return 11;
  }

}

public class Class1 {
  public int x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are misunderstanding assignment operation order.

"the right hand side expression is evaluated first and then assigned to the left hand side" means that you *assign* right value to left value after evaluating right value. It does not say anything about an order of evaluating left value.

In Java, you first evaluate left side, then you evaluate right side, and then you assign right side to left side. You can verify this by running following code:

```java
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        (c.echo("left")).x = tell(c.echo("right")); // Prints "left", then "right"
    }

    private static int tell(Object o) {
        return 11;
    }

}

public class Class1 {
    public int x;

    public Class1 echo(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
c.x = tell(c = null);
```

What's happening is:

1. c is set to null (c = null)
2. Then the call to tell happens, and that returns an integer
3. Then it tries to set c.x but c is now null